# Can I use Hbase to store hierarchy data format just like a very deep Json format

Tags: hbase

I was using MongoDB, but now I have to use Hbase for a new project. I have very complicated Json docs such as:
`{"comapy":[{"micro":{"hit":"no"}},{"cisco":{"hit":"yes"}}]}.`

I would like to query my data via nested fields, such as: company.cisco.hit='yes', and the nested field may much deeper. So how can I use Hbase to query these nested fields please, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store raw json data in hbase since hbase column values are basic byte arrays. But you can not query on this json like xx.yy.zz=1 because hbase is not a document database as mongo db or couchbase.

Maybe you can implement custom ColumnValueFilter if your json format is fixed for every value in table, but this does not make sense for a hbase project. If you want to query json fields, i think you should use a document store type nosql database.